# How can I change the path of images/files inside different views?

Tags: php, file, laravel, routes

This is working fine to show all the images inside the public folder of my home.blade view at www.mygallery.com

```
    @foreach($items as $item)
<div class="box">
<div class="boxInner">
<a href="{{$item->url}}"><img src="{{$item->image}}" alt="{{$item->title}}"></a>

</div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

By the way this is how my routes file looks like.

```
Route::get('', array('as'=>'itemshome', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@show_items'));
Route::resource('upload', 'ItemsController');
Route::get('tags/{category?}', array('as'=>'itemstag', 'uses'=>'ItemsController@show_items'));
```

But when I try to filter results by category (www.mygallery.com/tags/cats) $item->image is trying to reach every image at tags/images/myimage.jpg which of course doesn't exist.

The thing is that I don't want to create a public/tags/images folder, so I wonder how can I explicitly point to the correct folder (public/images) no matter what view/route is making the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `$item->image` is a relative path. So depending on your current URL you will link to different paths.

To generate an **absolute** URL, use the `asset()` function:

```
<a href="{{$item->url}}"><img src="{{ asset($item->image) }}" alt="{{$item->title}}"></a>
```